# Trying to create an onItemClickListener

Tags: android, listview, onclicklistener

I'm trying to making a listview where you can click on individual items in the list to bring up a deletion dialog. But for some reason I'm not getting any reaction from the listener when i click on the list. Here is the code for the main activity

```
 public class LifeRpgMain extends Activity {
ArrayList<String> List_Data=new ArrayList<String>();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_life_rpg_main);
    if(savedInstanceState!=null){
        System.out.println("this shouldnt happen");
        ArrayList<String> inp = (ArrayList<String>) savedInstanceState.get("positive");
        System.out.println("game made");
        List_Data.addAll(inp);


    }
    else{
        List_Data.add("run a mile");
        List_Data.add("do homework");
        List_Data.add("make this stupid app");
        List_Data.add("make money");
    }
    ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter(this, 
            R.layout.list_item, List_Data);


    ListView gameList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.main_list_view);
    gameList.setAdapter(adapter);
    //this should allow us to choose individual list items for deletion
    gameList.setChoiceMode(1);
    gameList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> paren, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            DeleteButtonFragment del = new DeleteButtonFragment(position, List_Data);
            del.show(fm, "delete button");
        }


    });




}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.life_rpg_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    savedInstanceState.putStringArrayList("positive", List_Data);
}
public void listAdd(View v){
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    AddButtonFragment add = new AddButtonFragment(findViewById(R.id.activityname),List_Data);
    add.show(fm, "teampicker");
}



 }
```

Here is the code for the listadapter

```
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
Context context; 
int layoutResourceId;    
ArrayList<String> data = null;

public ListAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<String> List_Data) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, List_Data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = List_Data;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    ItemHolder holder = null;
    if(row == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        holder = new ItemHolder();
        holder.name = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.ItemName);
        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ItemHolder)row.getTag();
    }

    String s = data.get(position);
    holder.name.setText(s);
    return row;

}

static class ItemHolder{

    TextView name;

}
}
```

Comment: Is `v` a variable we should know about ?

Comment: sorry that was a dinosaur, I fixed it.

Comment: And `DeleteButtonFragment` ?

Comment: @Snicolas DeleteButtonFragment is just a dialogfragment, I know that works because i've used it elsewhere, and I know that the itemclicklistener isnt working because i've tried placing test statements inside of the listener.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> paren, View view,
            int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i("Value", List_Data.get(position));

    }
```

Comment: I tried the code and i'm not getting any logs on the position. Could it because I have it set on the OnCreate? if so, then i'm not sure what other function I could do...

Comment: @DanielImberman strange.. remove ` gameList.setChoiceMode(1);` and see if you get any Log Register

Answer (score 0):

**Remove** this **Inner itemclicklistener**-

```
gameList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){   

 @Override
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> paren, View view,
      int position, long id) {
        Log.i("Value", List_Data.get(position));

    }
});
```